# Dynamic array and how to check if it has a certain number

Tags: arrays

I'm having trouble with dynamic array. The code I wrote is suppose to input the # of coins and check if 1 is included. If it is not include in the arrays include 1 to the array. But the array size is "fixed" so i can't change the size of array while keeping the other numbers inputted. How can I do this without messing up with my arrays?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,coin;
    cout << "Enter the value N to produce: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter number of different coins: " << endl;
    cin >> coin;
    int *S = new int[coin];
    cout << "Enter the denominations to use with a space after it" << endl;
    cout << "(1 will be added if necessary): " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < coin; i++)
    {
        cin >> S[i];
        if(S[i] != 1)
           S[coin] = 1;    // confused at this part of how to set the last element to 1
        cout << S[i] << endl;
    }
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is a logical inconsistency with your requirement.  Assume none of the  entered numbers is 1. You have two choices either overwrite one of the values or increase the size of the array by 1.

Comment: yea that the problem :/  i want to not overwrite the value and create the size of the array by 1. However if 1 is already include i won't need to increase the array by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is pseudo code/comments

```
 bool hasOne;
 for(int i = 0; i < coin; i++) {
        cin >> S[i];
        if(S[i] == 1) hasOne = true;
 }
 if(!hasOne) {
    // create a new array size one more than S
    // copy elements from S to the new array
    // set the last element to 1 in the new array
    // assign the new array to S
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to append 1 to the end of the array? If so, I would use std::vector object instead of an array

```
#include <vector>

vector<int> S;

for(int i = 0; i < coin; i++)
    {
        cin >> S[i];
        if(S[i] != 1)
           S.push_back(1);   
        cout << S[i] << endl;
    }
```

If you must use arrays you need to use malloc() to dynamically allocate memory. But since you are using c++ std::vector is the way to go.

Comment: hmm it doesn't have to be at the end of the array it can be anywhere in the array

Comment: S.push_back(1) will append a 1 to the vector increasing the vector size by 1 each time it is called.  You have logical flaws in your loop though. You want to independently:
1. Gather your input data and store it into a vector
2. Loop through the vector data and check for 1's 
3. If you find a 1 set a boolean flag and break out of the loop
4. If the flag is not set use push_back() to append a 1